# Make all properties lower case or upper case using reflect?

Tags: go

I am receiving unknown json from client and I parse to interface like

```
var f interface{}
err := json.Unmarshal(b, &f)
```

How to make all keys in f to be lower keys ?
I have to save this f to mongo and I need to make some queries but I want to avoid mistake if somebody send uppercase same json.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
var v any
err := json.Unmarshal(b, &v)
v = lower(v)
```

where lower is:

```
func lower(v any) any {
    switch v := v.(type) {
    case []any:
        lv := make([]any, len(v))
        for i := range v {
            lv[i] = lower(v[i])
        }
        return lv
    case map[string]any:
        lv := make(map[string]any, len(v))
        for mk, mv := range v {
            lv[strings.ToLower(mk)] = mv
        }
        return lv
    default:
        return v
    }
}
```

The `lower` function calls itself recursively to handle key conversion in nested JSON objects and arrays.

[playground](https://go.dev/play/p/IpSemNkxZnQ)

If you know that you are working with an object without nesting (the object fields do not contain arrays or other objects), then you can inline the map case from the `lower` function above:

```
var v map[string]any
err := json.Unmarshal(b, &v)
lv := make(map[string]any, len(v))
for mk, mv := range v {
    lv[strings.ToLower(mk)] = mv
}
v = lv
```

Comment: In the second case, you would want to recursively iterate over the map value as well: 
`for k, v := range f { lf[strings.ToLower(k)] = lower(v) }`

Comment: In the first solution maps are being re-created while slices not. Thus, keys from maps embedded in any slice are being changed also in the original (while other keys not). To maintain the original the same, it would be something like https://go.dev/play/p/t6zk672MFDF.

Answer (score 3):

It will be `map[string]interface{}` so go over it and simply convert keys to lowercase.

```
var f map[string]interface{}
...

converted := make(map[string]interface{}, len(f))
for k, v := range f {
    converted[strings.ToLower(k)] = v
}
```